# Wrapper List Sort by 2 text values

Tags: sort, wrapper-class, comparable, text

I have a wrapper class with 2 text values. I sorted them using Comparable. It works fine for one value.

Here, I have AreaName and ADName.  With the below I'm able to successfully sort by AreaName.  Now I want to sort with 2 values i.e., **if AreaName is same, then sort by ADName.** How?

```
global class AreaWrapper implements Comparable{
    public String AreaName{get;set;}
    public String ADName{get;set;}

    public AreaWrapper(){
        AreaName = '';
        ADName = '';
    }       

    global Integer compareTo(Object objToCompare) {
        //Sort by AreaName Alphabetically
        return AreaName.compareTo(((geoAreaWrapperInner)objToCompare).AreaName);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value 0 is returned when the values are the same so for that case compare the other field:

```
global Integer compareTo(Object objToCompare) {
    AreaWrapper that = (AreaWrapper) objToCompare;
    Integer c = this.AreaName.compareTo(that.AreaName);
    if (c != 0) {
        return c;
    } else {
        return this.ADName.compareTo(that.ADName);
    }
}
```